# What is the correct pronunciation of "espontaneidad?"

Tags: pronunciación

Primero mi pregunta en español:

**¿Cuál es la pronunciación correcta de "espontaneidad"?**

**Details in English:**

I was recently in the process of collecting some audio from [**Forvo**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Forvo) to add to a [**Memrise**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memrise) course I was making and one of the words I wanted to add was "espontaneidad."  As I waited for my computer to pull up the page of audio recordings for this word, I wondered how it would be pronounced and discovered that all three of the Forvo contributors treated the "ei" as a [**monophthong**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monophthong) instead of as a [**dipthong**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diphthong) as I had assumed.  I initially thought, *Well I'm glad I checked because I hadn't been pronouncing it like that.*  For some reason, however, I decided to see if [**WordReference**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WordReference.com) had any audio recording of it and what I found there surprised me a bit because the pronunciation differed ever so slightly.  Below you will find links to both the Forvo recordings and the WordReference recordings:

### [**Forvo pronunciations of "espontaneidad"**](https://forvo.com/word/espontaneidad/#es)

### [**WordReference entry for "espontaneidad"**](http://www.wordreference.com/es/en/translation.asp?spen=espontaneidad)

*(Click on the drop down menu to the right of the WordReference entry to select a pronunciation from Mexico, Spain, or Argentina.)*

Do you hear the difference?  What's the correct way to pronounce this word?  In other words, should I pronounce the “ei” combination like “ay” or like “AY-i"?  (Please forgive my lack of sophistication in transcribing sound.  I am neither a linguist nor a student of the International Phonetic Alphabet.)

**Detalles en español:**

Recientemente estaba en el proceso de colectar audio de Forvo para añadir a un curso de Memrise que estaba creando y una de las palabras que quería añadir fue “espontaneidad”.  Mientras esperaba mi computadora para mostrarme la página con descargables grabaciones de audio, me preguntaba cómo sería pronunciada y descubrí que cada uno de las tres contribuyentes de Forvo consideró la combinación “ei” como una vocal pura (o [**monoptongo**](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vocal)) en lugar de un [**diptongo**](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diptongo).  Inicialmente, pensé que *Pues, me alegre que las verifiqué porque no había estado pronunciándola como eso.*  Por alguna razón, sin embargo, decidí ver si [**WordReference**](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/WordReference.com) tenía grabaciones de esta palabra y lo que descubrí allí me sorprendió un poco porque la pronunciación era un poquito diferente.  Por debajo encontrarán enlaces a tanto las grabaciones de Forvo como las grabaciones de WordReference:

[Véanse arriba en la sección inglesa.]

*(Hagan clic en menú descendente a la derecha de la entrada en WordReference para seleccionar una pronunciación de México, España, o Argentina.)*

¿Oyen la diferencia?  ¿Cuál es la manera correcta de pronunciar esta palabra?  En otras palabras, ¿debería pronunciar la combinación “ei” como “ay” o como “AY-i”?  (Perdonen mi falta de sofisticación en transcribir sonido.  No soy ni una lingüista ni una estudiante del Alfabeto Fonético Internacional.)

Answer (score 5):

Etymologically, there is a hiatus: /es.pon.ta.ne.i'dad/

That said, in words that have hiatuses where the weak vowel is not also the stressed syllable of the word, there is a strong tendency for speakers to form a diphthong. All speakers may end up doing it, and it may be influenced by dialect, register, rate of speech, etc. This is partly why Spanish never developed a way to indicate such hiatuses (outside of poetry) — they are not consistent and never distinguish words.

So you can freely say /es.pon.ta.ne.i'dad/ or /es.pon.ta.nej'dad/ and it's doubtful speakers will even notice which you chose.

Answer (score 2):

First, let's make sure we're on the same page about E being a strong vowel and I being a weak one, which means that without a written accent, these two vowels together would form *one* syllable.  I *think* your question implies that you're clear about this but I just wanted to make sure.

I listened to the six pronunciations and I see that some people are a little sloppy with the "ei" syllable.  I don't see this as a big deal.  In English some people are sloppy with the T in "butter" and some people aren't.  Both of these cases have a degree of variation I can live with.

Strictly speaking, the first Forvo pronunciation, that shows a clear distinction between the two vowels in this syllable, is **the correct one**.

I, for one, as a non-native speaker of Spanish, tend to feel reassured when I hear this degree of variation among native speakers, because it tells me I can relax a bit and afford to be just a bit sloppy here and there from time to time.

Comment: Great answer and a likely candidate for the green checkmark.  Thank you, also, for specifying which of them you felt was the most correct.  In fact, I was just uploading audio to my course a few seconds ago and not sure if I should just go with what I had, and practice with what might be less than perfect pronunciations (as I might be forced to do in real life) or be a little patient and see if anybody had answered this question.  It was a pleasant surprise to see a good answer here already because I believe you sound like what you choose to listen to.  So, gracias for your rapid response.